# R sequence of dates with lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

Hi I'm trying to get a sequence of dates with lubridate

This doesn't work

```
seq(ymd('2012-04-07'),ymd('2013-03-22'),by=week(1))
```

the base command

```
seq(as.Date('2012-04-7'),as.Date('2013-03-22'),'weeks')
```

does, but I'd like to know if there is an elegant way to do this with lubridate.

**EDIT**

Please ignore : solved myself so leaving up for posterity only. Happy to have this deleted if necessary.

```
seq(ymd('2012-04-07'),ymd('2013-03-22'),by='weeks')
```

Does the trick

Comment: thanks @shujaa mnel got there with a helpful and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`ymd` is a wrapper to parse date strings and returns a `POSIXct` object.

You simply need to use standard terminology described in `?seq.POSIXt` (not `lubridate`) to define weeks

```
seq(ymd('2012-04-07'),ymd('2013-03-22'), by = '1 week')
seq(ymd('2012-04-07'),ymd('2013-03-22'), by = 'weeks')
```

will works

as will

```
seq(ymd('2012-04-07'),ymd('2013-03-22'), by = '2 week')
```

You could coerce the `lubridate` `Period` class object to a `difftime`, but that seems rather unnecessary

```
seq(ymd('2012-04-07'),ymd('2013-03-22'), by = as.difftime(weeks(1)))
```

Comment: Is there any way to get a sequence of `POSIXct` formatted objects? I want to use my date-sequence for a custom x-axis, and `POSIXt` doesn't match the plot's data (it's all POSIXct from lubridate output).

Comment: A caution that the base R approach doesn't always do the same as lubridate's Period. `seq(as.Date("2001-01-31"), as.Date("2001-12-31"), "months")` gives surprising results, for instance.

Answer (score 12):

This is a way to stick within the `POSIXct` universe of `lubridate` and not change date formats to base R's `POSIXt`. I avoid changing the date format in my scripts because I find it is a common place where bugs (for example time-zone changes or losing timestamps) are introduced. It follows this advice to use `%m+%`: [R: adding 1 month to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681229/r-adding-1-month-to-a-date)

```
# example date is a leap day for a "worst case scenario"
library("lubridate")
posixct.in <- parse_date_time(x = "2016-02-29", orders = "ymd")
# [1] "2016-02-29 UTC"

posixct.seq <- posixct.in %m+% years(x = seq.int(from = 0, to = 3, by = 1))
# [1] "2016-02-29 UTC" "2017-02-28 UTC" "2018-02-28 UTC" "2019-02-28 UTC"

posixct.seq <- posixct.in %m+% months(x = seq.int(from = 0, to = 3, by = 1))
# [1] "2016-02-29 UTC" "2016-03-29 UTC" "2016-04-29 UTC" "2016-05-29 UTC"

posixct.seq <- posixct.in %m+% days(x = seq.int(from = 0, to = 3, by = 1))
# [1] "2016-02-29 UTC" "2016-03-01 UTC" "2016-03-02 UTC" "2016-03-03 UTC"

posixct.seq <- posixct.in %m+% weeks(x = seq.int(from = 0, to = 3, by = 1))
# [1] "2016-02-29 UTC" "2016-03-07 UTC" "2016-03-14 UTC" "2016-03-21 UTC"
```

A regular `+` also works sometimes, but the `%m+%` prevents errors like this:

```
posixct.seq <- posixct.in + years(x = seq.int(from = 0, to = 3, by = 1))
# [1] "2016-02-29 UTC" NA               NA               NA
```

At first I was confused because I thought `%m+` was just a way to add months, and similar `lubridate` commands like `%y+%` etc. do not exist. But, turns out the "m" doesn't stand for "month addition". My best guess is "magic" =)

Comment: Thank you for this post. The comment regarding `%m+%` was particularly helpful. Lubridate is extremely powerful, but the documentation isn't great for things like the `%m_%` operator. I too had been assuming that it was constrained to shifting dates by month(s)

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be useful to others but I've written a more general function for calculating date sequences using a combination of lubridate, base and timechange.
It allows for either period or duration (base) arithmetic.

```r
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(timeplyr)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
seq(ymd('2012-04-07'),ymd('2013-03-22'),by='weeks')
#>  [1] "2012-04-07" "2012-04-14" "2012-04-21" "2012-04-28" "2012-05-05"
#>  [6] "2012-05-12" "2012-05-19" "2012-05-26" "2012-06-02" "2012-06-09"
#> [11] "2012-06-16" "2012-06-23" "2012-06-30" "2012-07-07" "2012-07-14"
#> [16] "2012-07-21" "2012-07-28" "2012-08-04" "2012-08-11" "2012-08-18"
#> [21] "2012-08-25" "2012-09-01" "2012-09-08" "2012-09-15" "2012-09-22"
#> [26] "2012-09-29" "2012-10-06" "2012-10-13" "2012-10-20" "2012-10-27"
#> [31] "2012-11-03" "2012-11-10" "2012-11-17" "2012-11-24" "2012-12-01"
#> [36] "2012-12-08" "2012-12-15" "2012-12-22" "2012-12-29" "2013-01-05"
#> [41] "2013-01-12" "2013-01-19" "2013-01-26" "2013-02-02" "2013-02-09"
#> [46] "2013-02-16" "2013-02-23" "2013-03-02" "2013-03-09" "2013-03-16"
time_seq(ymd('2012-04-07'),ymd('2013-03-22'),by='weeks')
#>  [1] "2012-04-07" "2012-04-14" "2012-04-21" "2012-04-28" "2012-05-05"
#>  [6] "2012-05-12" "2012-05-19" "2012-05-26" "2012-06-02" "2012-06-09"
#> [11] "2012-06-16" "2012-06-23" "2012-06-30" "2012-07-07" "2012-07-14"
#> [16] "2012-07-21" "2012-07-28" "2012-08-04" "2012-08-11" "2012-08-18"
#> [21] "2012-08-25" "2012-09-01" "2012-09-08" "2012-09-15" "2012-09-22"
#> [26] "2012-09-29" "2012-10-06" "2012-10-13" "2012-10-20" "2012-10-27"
#> [31] "2012-11-03" "2012-11-10" "2012-11-17" "2012-11-24" "2012-12-01"
#> [36] "2012-12-08" "2012-12-15" "2012-12-22" "2012-12-29" "2013-01-05"
#> [41] "2013-01-12" "2013-01-19" "2013-01-26" "2013-02-02" "2013-02-09"
#> [46] "2013-02-16" "2013-02-23" "2013-03-02" "2013-03-09" "2013-03-16"

# Months example

# Notice the difference between seq and time_seq
time_seq(dmy("31-01-2012"), dmy("31-01-2013"), by = "month")
#>  [1] "2012-01-31" "2012-02-29" "2012-03-31" "2012-04-30" "2012-05-31"
#>  [6] "2012-06-30" "2012-07-31" "2012-08-31" "2012-09-30" "2012-10-31"
#> [11] "2012-11-30" "2012-12-31" "2013-01-31"
seq(dmy("31-01-2012"), dmy("31-01-2013"), by = "month")
#>  [1] "2012-01-31" "2012-03-02" "2012-03-31" "2012-05-01" "2012-05-31"
#>  [6] "2012-07-01" "2012-07-31" "2012-08-31" "2012-10-01" "2012-10-31"
#> [11] "2012-12-01" "2012-12-31" "2013-01-31"

# DST example
dst <- dmy_hms("26-03-2023 00:00:00", tz = "GB")

# Base R
seq(dst, length.out = 5,
         by = "hour")
#> [1] "2023-03-26 00:00:00 GMT" "2023-03-26 02:00:00 BST"
#> [3] "2023-03-26 03:00:00 BST" "2023-03-26 04:00:00 BST"
#> [5] "2023-03-26 05:00:00 BST"
time_seq(dst, length.out = 5,
         by = "hour",
         seq_type = "duration")
#> [1] "2023-03-26 00:00:00 GMT" "2023-03-26 02:00:00 BST"
#> [3] "2023-03-26 03:00:00 BST" "2023-03-26 04:00:00 BST"
#> [5] "2023-03-26 05:00:00 BST"
# Period arithmetic
time_seq(dst, length.out = 5,
         roll_dst = "NA",
         by = "hour",
         seq_type = "period")
#> [1] "2023-03-26 00:00:00 GMT" NA                       
#> [3] "2023-03-26 02:00:00 BST" "2023-03-26 03:00:00 BST"
#> [5] "2023-03-26 04:00:00 BST"
time_seq(dst, length.out = 5,
         roll_dst = "pre",
         by = "hour",
         seq_type = "period")
#> [1] "2023-03-26 00:00:00 GMT" "2023-03-26 00:00:00 GMT"
#> [3] "2023-03-26 02:00:00 BST" "2023-03-26 03:00:00 BST"
#> [5] "2023-03-26 04:00:00 BST"
time_seq(dst, length.out = 5,
         roll_dst = "post",
         by = "hour",
         seq_type = "period")
#> [1] "2023-03-26 00:00:00 GMT" "2023-03-26 02:00:00 BST"
#> [3] "2023-03-26 02:00:00 BST" "2023-03-26 03:00:00 BST"
#> [5] "2023-03-26 04:00:00 BST"

# You can also mix dates and datetimes

seq(ymd('2012-04-07'), now(), by = "years")
#> Error in seq.Date(ymd("2012-04-07"), now(), by = "years"): 'to' must be a "Date" object
time_seq(ymd('2012-04-07'), now(), by = "years")
#>  [1] "2012-04-07 UTC" "2013-04-07 UTC" "2014-04-07 UTC" "2015-04-07 UTC"
#>  [5] "2016-04-07 UTC" "2017-04-07 UTC" "2018-04-07 UTC" "2019-04-07 UTC"
#>  [9] "2020-04-07 UTC" "2021-04-07 UTC" "2022-04-07 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>